# Getting data from access databse according to year

Tags: .net, database, ms-access, pivot, pivot-table

I am working on one application and I got stuck; I need to query in a way that I can get data from access database according to year.

Ex: I have one row where startdate is 1-09-2016 and enddate is 2-6-2017. I want to get the month number between the startdate and enddate year wise

like:

> 9,10,11,12 for 2016
>
> and 1,2....,6 for 2017

Is there any way to do that?

i am using pivot table to get Month number but it showing wrong results as it contains only Jan to Dec fields.

if the date is in next year then it is showing wrong results
ex: For date 22 nov 2016 to 2 feb 2017
expected result is
11(for nov)
12(for december) for 2016
and 1,2 for 2017

here is my query

> TRANSFORM iif( IsNull(COUNT(monthTable.monthNumber)),"N/A",FIRST(Resource_Allocation.[Chargebility]))
>   SELECT  Resource_Allocation.[Employee ID], Resource_Allocation.[Actual Roll-On Date], Resource_Allocation.[Estimated Roll-Off Date]
>   FROM Resource_Allocation, monthTable
>   WHERE monthTable.monthNumber Between month([Resource_Allocation]![Actual Roll-On Date]) And Month([Resource_Allocation]![Estimated Roll-Off Date])
>   GROUP BY Resource_Allocation.[Employee ID],  Resource_Allocation.[Actual Roll-On Date], Resource_Allocation.[Estimated Roll-Off Date]
>   PIVOT monthTable.monthName IN(January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December);

Comment: You just need a number on months between two dates? Is it Sql query?

Comment: no i need month number not count of months :)

Comment: like 01 for jan 06 for june 07 for july and so on.

Comment: in what format do you need the result: records? fields in a record? a concatenated field?...

Answer (score 0):

Here is example how to do it on sample data:

```
DECLARE @Start  DATETIME,
        @End    DATETIME;

SELECT   @Start = '2016-09-01'        
    ,@End   = '2017-06-02';


SELECT  MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, a.number, @Start)) as MonthNumber
FROM    master.dbo.spt_values a
WHERE   a.type = 'P'        
AND     a.number <= DATEDIFF(MONTH, @Start, @End);
```

Provide more data about actual table/columns names if You need more help with that.

Comment: Question is about ms-access.

Answer (score 0):

If you want resolve this in MS Access, here's a quick and dirty approach.
Create a table tblMonth having two columns, YearNr and MonthNr (numeric).
Enter all required data (2016 1, 2016 2 et cetera).
Next, run this query (query will ask you to enter a startdate and enddate being your date range):

```
PARAMETERS StartDate date, EndDate Date;
SELECT tblMonth.YearNr, tblMonth.MonthNr
FROM tblMonth
WHERE YearNr & Format(MonthNr, '00')>= Year(StartDate) & Format(Month(StartDate),'00')
AND YearNr & Format(MonthNr,'00') <= Year(EndDate) & Format(Month(EndDate),'00')
```